# Dynamically deleting and loading Screen object in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am currently developing an embedded system with kivy.

Therefore, I found that if I make many screens, it slows down the program a lot.

Is there a good way to dynamically control screens so it does not slow down?

For instance, when I have 4 screens in ScreenManager like below,

```
MyScreenManager:
    id: myscreenmanager
    transition: FadeTransition()
    SCRN_LOADING:
    SCRN_IDLE:
    SCRN_CALCULATING:
    SCRN_RESULT:
```

Would it be possible to:

1. innitially load `SCRN_LOADING` first.
2. loads `SCRN_IDLE` and `SCRN_CALCULATING` while loading.
3. when loading is done, remove `SCRN_LOADING` screen object.
4. loads `SCRN_RESULT` while calculating.
5. when going back to idle, remove `SCRN_RESULT` screen object.

I am guessing this could improve performance.

Currently, the screen lags really hard. So I might have to restart the whole project using C if I can't solve the performance issue.

Please help me out!

Comment: Does the entire app slow down? Or does just the initial loading slow down? Or is it only the transition between screens that is slow? Have you tried `NoTransition`?

Comment: @JohnAnderson The entire app slows down. I am guessing that `ScreenManager` holds all the screens all the time because when I move the screens back and forth, the things (such as what I typed in textbox) remain the same. And when I temporarily removed some screens and tested, the app got faster. So I am trying to find out if I can improve the performance by dynamically making and removing screens instead of holding all the screens in the app.

Comment: I believe that you can use `add_widget` and `remove_widget` to keep just the `Screens` that you want handy.  In your `.kv` file only include `SCRN_LOADING` as a child of the `ScreenManager`, and only include rules like `<SCRN_IDL>:` for the other screens. Then create a `SCRN_IDLE()` screen and use `add_widget` to add it (and the `current` to show it). You could also try the `switch_to()` method to do the remove, add, and show in one operation.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could declare your screens outside kv and then add them as required in your screen manager,In your kv

```
MyScreenManager:
    id: myscreenmanager
    transition: FadeTransition()
```

In your Window class:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

...
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.sm = self.ids.myscreenmanager
    self.loading = Screen(name='SCRNLOADING')
    self.idle = Screen(name='SCRN_IDLE')
    self.calc = Screen(name='SCRN_CALCULATING')
    self.sm.add_widget(self.loading)
    self.set_idle()

def add_scrn(self):
    self.sm.add_widget(self.idle)
    self.sm.add_widget(self.calc)
    self.sm.remove_widget(self.loading)
```

Im not really used to the `Clock` class but I'm sure you will need it here to load your screens correctly